# How do I present a Stripe Customer's list of cards?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I simply want to show a user's default Stripe payment method within an iOS app.

I’m trying to push an `STPPaymentMethodsViewController` onto a `viewController`. Stripe explicitly states that I have to create an `STPCustomerContext`. Do I have to create an `STPPaymentContext` as well? I don't want to create an `STPPaymentContext` because it requires 4 methods that I won't use in this part of my app... Here is what I have, but no dice.

Also, Stripe's docs instruct you to create a customerContext, but don't say how that is passed to the `STPPaymentMethodsViewController`. What am I missing?

https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/custom

```
//AppDelegate.swift
var customerContext: STPCustomerContext?

func setupStripe() {
    self.customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient.sharedClient)
}
```

From the user's settingsVC I'm trying to do the following:

```
    func paymentMethodsButtonTapped() {
    let paymentMethodsViewController = STPPaymentMethodsViewController()
    paymentMethodsViewController.delegate = self // ERROR HERE: Cannot assign to property: 'delegate' is get only
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: paymentMethodsViewController)
    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: hello @Charles, did you get some solution

Comment: I would like to do the same thing, but after looking into STPPaymentMethodsViewController I didn't find a list or a tableview or anything...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class confirms to `STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeClient.shared)
let paymentMethodsViewController = STPPaymentMethodsViewController(configuration: STPPaymentConfiguration.shared(), theme: STPTheme.default(), customerContext: customerContext, delegate: self as STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate)
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: paymentMethodsViewController)
present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

Comment: from where you get the StripeClient.shared? Will you please share full code

Comment: I named it StripeClient but actually you can named as you want, that client should be created by you and it should contain some methods used by Stripe, you can get an example here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Example/Basic%20Integration/MyAPIClient.swift